# Material Exposed Dropdown Menu OnItemSelectedListener not being called

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I have an ExposedDropdownMenu implemented in my app, and while hamfisted, it gets the job done and I'm able to style it how I want it to look. On my country "spinner", i want the list of states to change to provinces if canada is selected, then be populated with a list of canadian provinces. When my "spinner" was an actual `Spinner`, `OnItemSelectedListener` worked flawlessly, however, it no longer is changing back and forth now that I've implemented the "spinner" as an EDM

Here is my code:

```
// get country spinner values and change state/zip options depending on country selected
val countryAdapter = MaterialSpinnerAdapter<String>(it, R.layout.material_spinner_item, it.resources.getStringArray(R.array.country))
country_dropdown.setAdapter(countryAdapter)
country_dropdown.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    displayStatesForSelectedCountry(position)
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    displayDefaultStatesList()
                }
}

    private fun displayStatesForSelectedCountry(position: Int) {
        context?.let {
            val canadaAdapter = MaterialSpinnerAdapter<String>(it, R.layout.material_spinner_item, it.resources.getStringArray(R.array.states_of_canada))

            when(position) {
                1 -> {
                    displayDefaultStatesList()
                }
                2 -> {
                    state_dropdown.setAdapter(canadaAdapter)
                    enrollment_zip_code.hint = it.resources.getString(R.string.enrollment_hint_postal_code)
                    enrollment_zip_code.editText?.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                }
                else -> displayDefaultStatesList()
            }
        }
    }
```

Thinking that maybe the behaviour has changed, I attempted to implement the `OnItemClickedListener` instead:

```
country_dropdown.setOnItemClickListener { parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                                                      view: View?,position:
                                                      Int,id: Long ->
                displayStatesForSelectedCountry(position)
            }
```

No dice. I know that the listener(s) are not being called at all because at the very least, the zipcode hint would change to postal code, however, it does not. What am I doing wrong here? should I not be using the position? if not, why not? `MaterialSpinnerAdapter` is just a subclass of `ArrayAdapter` to prevent filtering when I dont want it to filter, but i should be able to reliably use the position to determine what to show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It occurred to me that its a type of `EditText`, so this works:

```
            country_dropdown.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence?,
                    start: Int,
                    count: Int,
                    after: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    displayStatesForSelectedCountry(s.toString())
                    viewModel.country.value = s.toString()
                }
            })
```